# Docker Compose: Running a command and then retrieving files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Docker compose setup where I have 20 different services that depend on each other. I'm writing a script that runs tests on a container by using `docker-compose run my_service ...`.

I've got a couple of issues with that though:

1. After the tests finish, they should output both an XML file with the test results and an XML file with the coverage results. I want my script, which calls `docker-compose`, to have access to both of these files. This is a challenge because as far as I know, after running `docker-compose run`, these containers are shut down. The only solution I can think of is running it with `--entrypoint=tail -f /dev/null`, then executing the test command and retrieving the file. But that's a little cumbersome. Is there a better way?
2. After the tests finish, I'd like to stop and delete not only the container I was running tests on but all containers that were started because it was dependent on them. How can I do that automatically?

Comment: it is difficult to say without seeing what the dockerfile is look like

Answer (score 2):

> After the tests finish, they should output both an XML file...

If the main function of your task is to read or produce files to the local filesystem, it's often better to run it outside of Docker.  In the case of integration tests, this is even pretty straightforward: instead of running the tests inside a Docker container and pointing at the other containers' endpoints, run the tests on the host and point at their published ports.  If your test environment can run `docker-compose` commands then you can launch the container stack as a test fixture.

If for some reason they *have* to run in Docker, then you can bind-mount a host directory into the container to receive the result files.  [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) does support additional `-v` volume mounts, so you should be able to run something like

```
docker-compose run -v $PWD/my_service_tests:/output my_service ..
```

> I'd like to stop and delete not only the container I was running tests on but all containers that were started because it was dependent on them.

I don't think Docker Compose has that option; it's not *that* clever.  Consider the case of two different tests running at the same time, each running a separate test container but sharing a database container.  The first test can't stop the database container because the second test is using it, but Compose isn't really aware of this.

If you don't mind running a complete isolated stack for each test run, then you can use the [`docker-compose -p`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) option to do that.  Then you can use `docker-compose rm` to clean everything up, for that specific test run.

```
docker-compose -p test1 run -v $PWD/test1:/output my_service ...
docker-compose -p test1 stop
docker-compose -p test1 rm
```

Comment: "Consider the case of two different tests [...] sharing a database container". I thought that the point of `docker-compose run` was to run one-off commands that are separate from any running containers, no? The documentation says "Commands you use with run start in new containers" and "docker-compose run command does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration".
Are you sure that a container launched by `docker-container run` could be shared with unrelated containers?

Comment: Also, trying to use `-p` results in `ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space`, even after I stopped and deleted all containers.

Comment: If `my_service` `depends_on: db`, it will use an existing database container.  The example in the documentation uses `docker-compose run` to run migrations, which intrinsically needs to share the existing database.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. After the tests finish, they should output both an XML file with the test results and an XML file with the coverage results. I want my
>      script, which calls docker-compose, to have access to both of these
>      files.

You can write test reports to some folder inside the container. This folder may be mapped to folder on the Docker host using volumes. So script running `docker-compose` commands would be able to use them.

> This is a challenge because as far as I know, after running
>   docker-compose run, these containers are shut down.

They are stopped. But, the next time you run docker-compose up they are restarted [preserving mounted volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).

[Note](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#only-recreate-containers-that-have-changed):

> Compose caches the configuration used to create a container. When you
>   restart a service that has not changed, Compose re-uses the existing
>   containers. Re-using containers means that you can make changes to
>   your environment very quickly.

It means you can copy reports files generated by test service using `docker cp` commands even after containers exit.

`docker cp` should work regardless volumes. For example, suppose tests had written `reports.xml` to `/test_reports` folder insider the container. You can copy the file to the host using `docker cp` after test container has stopped.

[Example](https://github.com/jmenga/todobackend/blob/63159960a3bd2d39858408de90e01ee7aeb5a464/Makefile.v2#L53), [Example2](https://github.com/jmenga/todobackend/blob/63159960a3bd2d39858408de90e01ee7aeb5a464/Makefile.v2#L81)

> After the tests finish, I'd like to stop and delete not only the
>   container I was running tests on but all containers that were started
>   because it was dependent on them. How can I do that automatically?

Use `docker-compose down`

[The command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)

```
Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by up.
```

The command will work if you defined the service under test with all dependent services and test service itself in the same compose file.

[Usage example](https://github.com/jmenga/todobackend/blob/63159960a3bd2d39858408de90e01ee7aeb5a464/Makefile.v2#L85)